# Describe the set of all possible values of the given integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

let $\gamma$ be a closed and continuously differentiable path in the upper half
plane
$\{z \in C : z = x + iy, x, y \in R, y > 0\}$
not passing through the point $i$. Describe the set of all possible values of the
integral

$$\frac{1}{2i\pi}  \oint γ   \frac{2i}{z^2 +1}dz$$

i was taking $2i/z^2 +1$   after i try to find out the pole, and i know that pole will $\iota$. after this step i don't how to proceed further.

If anybody help me i would be very thankul to him...

Comment: If the curve winds around the point i, you can use the cauchy integral formula (don't forget to multiply by the number of times the curve winds around the point i as it might not be a simple curve) and if not, the integral will be zero by the cauchy-goursat theorem.

Comment: my teacher said that answer will be all the INTEGER , i don't know how it is possible @ zokomoko

Comment: Try and solve the integral given that the curve loops around the point z=i only once using the cauchy integral formula

Answer (score 0):

First of all for $f(z)=1/(z^2+1)$ we have $\text{Res}_{\pm i}(f)=\pm\frac{1}{2i}$.  Let $n_{\pm i}$ be the winding number of the closed curve $\gamma$ around the singularities $\pm i$.  By the residue theorem we get

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=2i\left(\frac{n_i}{2i}-\frac{n_{-i}}{2i}\right)=n_i-n_{-i}$

So indeed the the set of all possible values is $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Here $n_{-i}=0$  because the closed-curve is in the upper-half plane

Comment: @reuns Yes, but this requirement is needless. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well the objective is not to prove a result but to explain the underlying idea